# How can I split a String into an Array then return a given element?

Tags: java, string

I have a string like this: "Name foo Modified bar"

I want to split this string and then return only "foo". I have looked into splitting strings and found this:

```
String nameString = "Name foo Modified bar";
System.out.println(
    java.util.Arrays.toString(
    nameString.split(" ")
));
```

Output:

```
[Name, foo, Modified, bar]
```

I would like to be able to get "foo" on it's own, as a local variable. 
Something like this:

```
String name = output.get(1);
```

This would work if output was an ArrayList that namestring was split into.

How should I approach getting this result?
Should I use the string splitting method I have found or something else? Is there a way to split a string into an arraylist?

Thanks.

Comment: is what you want always going to be the 2nd element?  Or always going to be "foo"?

Comment: @Sean Kelly - array indexing is "Java 101" stuff.  I recommend that you take the time to do the Java tutorial, or read an introduction to Java programming book.

Comment: @StephenC Whilst true, I was getting confused with where the output was going to rather than the index. As demonstrated by the fact that I had code which would retrieve a given index from an ArrayList.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one line:

```
String name = nameString.split(" ")[1];
```

In two:

```
String []tokens = nameString.split(" ");
String name = tokens[1];
```

To create an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tokens));
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing is to grab the element from the array using square bracket notation:

```
String nameString = "Name foo Modified bar";
String name = nameString.split(" ")[1];
```

Or, if you particularly want it as a collection:

```
List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList(nameString.split(" "));
String name = nameList.get(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) returns an array.

So

```
String[] elems = nameString.split(" ");
String result = elems[1];
```

See the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) tutorial for more info.

Comment: Thanks but I think Doug Ramsey's answer is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

if you want ArrayList  -

```
new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList(nameString.split(" ") ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to split a string into an arraylist? 
Yes:

```
String toFindString="foo";
String nameString = "Name foo Modified bar";
List<String> nameStringList = Arrays.asList(nameString.split(" "));
```

To find any string from the list.

```
for (String string : nameStringList) {
        if(string.equals(toFindString)){
                return string;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think `Arrays.asList()` has to return an `ArrayList` (though it probably does). Can't you just keep it as a `List<String>` and lose the cast?